# Где используется ниббл?

Tags: системы-счисления

Для чего нужен ниббл, если есть байт? Хочу посмотреть примеры использования ниббл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копипаста, настало твое время

> В компьютерной графике иногда используется 4-битная глубина цвета, то есть палитра из 16 цветов. Особенно употребителен был 4-битный цвет для адаптеров EGA. LPT-порт, даже на самом старом PC, может передавать данные от принтера к компьютеру по одному нибблу, используя специальные линии состояния. Эта возможность используется некоторыми периферийными устройствами, подключаемыми через такой порт.
>
> Кодовая страница CP866
>   Октет состоит из двух нибблов. Шестнадцатеричное представление октетов (то есть разложение множества 256 значений октетов в прямое произведение 16×16) используется для наглядного представления этого множества, в частности для изображения кодовых страниц в виде таблиц. На рисунке — множество октетов (символы альтернативной кодировки) в виде таблицы. Слева отложен старший ниббл (возрастает снизу вверх), снизу отложен младший ниббл (возрастает слева направо).
>
> При использовании двоично-десятичного кода одна десятичная цифра хранится в одном ниббле.
>
> Аналогично метру, килограмму, литру, секунде и другим единицам измерения, в которых используются названия: полметра, полкилограмма, поллитра, полсекунды, а не их специальные названия, на практике применяется название — полубайт, а название ниббл не прижилось.

Источник: [Ниббл - Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BB)

От себя:

Лично я на практике сталкивался только с двоично-десятичным кодом во времена изучения ассемблера. В некоторых случаях он в разы удобее стандартного бинарного представления числа - например, преобразования числа в строку и обратно в нем проводятся гораздо проще. Не говоря уже про отладку.